npm publish Bad Request (400) child "params" fails
Trying to publish an unscoped package, doing everything that's in the docs
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/packagename - child "params" fails because ["params" must be an object]

This is the error I'm getting. The docs said all I have to do is to just run npm publish but the error seems to want argumnents?
I tried npm login, no use.

Having the same issue, yesterday everything worked.

@alex Looks like this is just an outage, their status now says "Failures publishing, deprecating, and installing packages"

yeah probably something broke down. Will try later. Cause yesterday was 0 problems.

@alex Works now!
